# how to call a PHTML file within a CMS page Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to call a phtml file within my cms page and it will not work.

this is the code in the cms page

`{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/form-top.phtml"}}`

fom-top.phtml basically opens a form but that does not matter. this code cause nothing past the header to be displayed.

any ideas on how to call a phtml file within a CMS page?

Comment: the syntax is right, I think the problem is related with form-top.phtml which the system can't find in the right path.

Comment: what other types could i use?

Comment: the file is in that directory

Comment: create a static block and use in cms page

Comment: i cannot call php within a static block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View the source of your webpage and scroll to the bottom to see a php error.

form-top.phtml gets called but there is a php error inside which fails. The error might happen in an invisible div that's why you don't see it the normal way.

Comment: what if there's no such error and still the phtml isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line with following code

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="catalog/product/form-top.phtml"}}
```