# Magento call customer first name in specific cms page

Tags: magento, variables, echo

I'm trying to call customer first name on one page. The page has already been restricted to logged in members only. So if you try to access the page and you haven't logged in, you will be redirected to login page.

How do I call, echo or display a logged in customer's first name on one specific CMS page?

I'm a noob trying to learn magento. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a customer name in a .phtml file

```
   echo Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomerName();
```

Read more @ [Current user in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416553/current-user-in-magento)

To get the customer name in  a cms page, I would call a phtml file from the cms page using

```
 {{block type="core/template" template="path/to/file/customer_name.phtml"}}
```

Read more @ [how to call a PHTML file within a CMS page Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602161/how-to-call-a-phtml-file-within-a-cms-page-magento)

Answer (score 5):

Magento Customers First Name get in  Logged in users

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

if($session->isLoggedIn())
{
    $customer = $session->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getFirstname();
}
```

Try to implement the above code to display the Customer First name your CMS Page.