# adding image from cms/pages/home/content

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am adding one image from cms/pages/home/content, and it's working.

But i don't know in which file these changes are reflected in the file system ?

is this a gud way to design a page or not ?

Comment: when u add images it actually add image in media>wysiwyg folder these page dosent reflect any file,,better way to page design is call phtml file from your cms page

Comment: it adds img tag to code displayed there, when i insert image. i thought it will reflect to specific file.

Comment: no it dosent reflect any file,,,if you want to see content you can directly see on database from cms_page table

Comment: and from where i should call phtml file? and what's best place to put this phtml file?

Comment: If you want to add single image, then you are doing right. No need to add phtml file. But If you want some slide show of some programing or database driven data or information. then go for phtml. help is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602161/how-to-call-a-phtml-file-within-a-cms-page-magento

Comment: No i want to design whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call phtml file this way

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/YOUR_FILE_NAME.phtml"}}
```

you can put this code in content of page

```
page/html/YOUR_FILE_NAME.phtml
```

this path of your phtml file this can be your path

Comment: if i add this code to cms, this will be stored in database. right ?. Is there anyway all these code stored in file not the database ?

Comment: no its not possible,,,cms content always store in Database...but what u want exactly?

Comment: its nothing, i just wanted to know if i can do it that way.